# What is the name of this widget?

Tags: android

I'm new to android. In the following picture, can someone tell me what the name of widget beside `Priority` TextView is?

[image]

Comment: where is the priority test view?

Comment: @WilliamKinaan - I'm pretty sure that the "Priority TextView" is the view that is displaying the text "Priority:".

Comment: It's most likely a `RadioGroup`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can style `RadioGroup` to look like that - you need to `@null` out "radio" drawable, leave the label alone and maybe create a custom selector for background.

Comment: have you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be ListView with images in it.

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to do what you want, I will give you one of them.

Five textviews in a horizontal orientation, in your Java class If the user clicks on any of them , change the background of that textview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv4"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv5"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Result**
[image]

**Note**
You can do the same thing using listview with textview in each listitem.